# Restarting list in which a style has been applied

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In a list I have been editing in Word 2013, there is an item in which the style **Heading 2** has been applied. It is the first item of the list's second level and it's labeled as an **f**.

[image]

I want the list's second level to be started over, in order words, to be numbered as **a** instead of **f**.

Nonetheless, when I right-click **Restart at a**, nothing happens.

[image]

If I try to adjust it by **Set Numbering Value**, the following message appears, yet, again, the situation doesn't change.

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Screen shot added